# Grafana Worldmap Panel event handler

Tags: javascript, dom-events, grafana, world-map

Is there a way to add event to Grafana Worldmap Panel points?

[image: click screenshot]

I would like for example click on circle or popup board and go to another dashboard. Is Grafana Worldmap Panel allows make something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not implemented yet. Once [this enhancement request](https://github.com/grafana/worldmap-panel/issues/27) is done then should be able to add links easily enough.